# Foreign Keys in DB2

Tags: foreign-keys, db2

I have some problems about db2 foreign keys.
I need to learn how to get foreign keys with table name,referential table name and column names in DB2.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is there any select query?

Comment: Your DB2 version and platform?

Comment: db2 express c server on my computer

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your computer screen from here very well; what operating system is installed?

Comment: Anyway, check out the catalog views `SYSCAT.REFERENCES` and `SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE` [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html)

Comment: I tried to use SYSCAT.REFERENCES and SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE but they were not enough.I need to use like "select constname,tabname.. from .."

Comment: We are not here to write your SQL for you.  Please provide example SQL that you have tried, ...